# Why does filebeat docker container exit without error and doing anything?

Tags: docker, filebeat

Im sure its a very simple question but I cant figure it out.
Im using the following setup:

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /usr/share/filebeat/applogs/*.log
-type:
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.8.23
COPY filebeatconfig/filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER root
RUN chown root:filebeat /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
RUN chmod go-w /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER filebeat
```

cmd

```
docker build -f filebeatconfig/ -t myfilebeat .
docker run --name myfb --network host \
-v $PWD/logs/:/usr/share/filebeat/applogs/ \
myfilebeat setup -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]
```

The connections to the local kibana and elastic search container are fine and I have a stub file that is constantly receiving more inputs.

Why does filebeat not do shit and exits after like 10 seconds after the following output?

```
Loaded index template
Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
Loaded dashboards
Loaded machine learning job configurations
```

The structure of the directory is below:

```
.
├── fakelogger.py
├── filebeatconfig
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── filebeat.yml
├── kb.yml
├── logs
    └── fake.log
```

Comment: Please put the tree structure of your folder and files

Comment: @xirehat tree structure added

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is with the extra `type:` in filebeat.yml